# code that will determine the appropriate dimensions to scale an image

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I did not understood also even the full part. Can anyone describe me what they wanted and how it can be done.

could you guide me on this.

Comment: They want you to determine the scale and target pixel size.  I think you need to figure this out yourself. It is simple math with the source and destination width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the aspect ratio must be maintained, that just means that you need to scale the height and width by exactly the same amount. That's a reasonably easy requirement to meet - you just calculate the desired scale and apply that to both dimensions.

In order to ensure the image only scaled *down,* you check only that *upper* limits are exceeded, and scale in those cases. For example if the height and width are both less than 1001, and the pixel count is less than 500,000 then you don't bother scaling at all.

The upper limits to check for the other requirements are as follows:

First, if the height is greater than 1000, simply scale both height and width by `1000/height`. This brings the height down to 1,000 and adjusts the width accordingly.

Following that, if the width is greater than 1000, simply scale both height and width (which may already have been scaled due to the height) by `1000/width`. This brings the width down to 1,000 and, again, maintains aspect ratio by scaling down the height by the same amount.

Lastly, you need to check the pixel count, which is calculated as `height * width`. With the height and width both 1,000 or less, you may still have a pixel count up to a million.

If it is over 500,000, you scale both height and width in such a way that the pixel count comes below that value. Because it's a *two-dimensional* value, you scale by the *square root* of `500,000 / (height * width)`.

So, in terms of pseudo-code, you're looking at something like:

```
if h > 1,000:
    scale = 1,000 / h
    h = h * scale       # will be 1,000
    w = w * scale

if w > 1,000:
    scale = 1,000 / w
    h = h * scale
    w = w * scale       # will be 1,000

if h * w > 500,000:
    scale = sqrt (500,000 / (h * w))
    h = h * scale
    w = w * scale
```

Checking that third section of code with some sample values (800 by 700, giving 560,000 pixels) yields the following:

```
  800 * sqrt (500K/560K) -> 755
  700 * sqrt (500K/560K) -> 611

  755 * 611 -> 499,055 pixels, so scaled down okay.
  Ratio of 755/611 is same (roughly) as 800/700.
```

Comment: +1 Hired. Nice  writeup... I never heard "two-dimensional value" used for "w*h"... also I have no idea how I'd call it.